# Changing the numpy array into required shape

Tags: python, numpy, gis

I have 2d numpy array of 480 rows and 1440 columns as named by 'data' below:

```
The first element belongs to (49.875S,179.875W),
the second element belongs to (49.625S,179.625W),
and the last element belongs to (49.875N,179.875E).

import os, glob, gdal, numpy as np

fname = '3B42RT.2014010606.7.bin'

with open(fname, 'rb') as fi:
    fi.seek(2880,0)
    data = np.fromfile(fi,dtype=np.uint16,count=480*1440)
    data = data.byteswap()
    data = data.reshape(1440,480)
```

How can I convert this numpy array so that its first element belongs to (49.875N,179.625W), i.e., upper left latitude and longitude respectively; and the last element belong to (49.625S,179.875E), i.e., lower right latitute and longitude respectively.

I tried to rotate it, but I do not think it is correct.

```
 data = np.rot90(data,1)
```

Have some of you experienced with this type of problem?
The binary file I am using is here: ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/merged/3B42RT/3B42RT.2014010606.7.bin.gz

Comment: What do you mean by "belongs to"?

Comment: the first element correspond to (49.875S,179.875W). It is a raster data, so the coordinate of the first element is (49.875S,179.875W)

Comment: It's still not clear what that's supposed to mean. Are you supposed to put the element that originally corresponded to (49.875N,179.625W) in the first spot? Or are you supposed to somehow transform the element so it represents (49.875N,179.625W)? Where in the array was the original element for (49.875N,179.625W)? And what the heck is the second element of a 2D array?

Comment: I want to transform the elements so that the transformed array will match to the required coordinates.

Comment: @Drakos: It's not clear at all how your data corresponds to any kind of geography at all. Can you be more explicit than giving three coordinates? Do your rows and columns correspond to lines of lattitude and longitude (or vice versa)? Where is the "second" element you refer to in the data (is it `data[0,1]`, or something else)?

Comment: @Drakos it seems you want to sort the array in descending order for the first column and ascending order for the second column, is that right?

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, the rows and columns correspond to lons and lats respectively

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to *register* points on a sphere to a set of pre-defined reference points. In other words: What is the *transformation* that *maps* your ```data``` points onto "first/second/third element". This is an absolutely nontrivial problem! You need to deal with spherical coordinates or project it to some local coordinate plane, both of which is mainly a mathematic/geometric/geodetic problem rather a matter of Python commands.

Comment: @SaulloCastro the rows and columns of the data and the lats and lons are different array. you can assume the lons and lats as another array

Comment: @Falko yes you have understood my problem, but I already applied rot90 in order to transform into the required coordinate. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: @Drakos: No, that's far from being correct. It's not even a coordinate transform, but just mixes x and y of different points. It rotates the coordinate matrix around 90 degrees (similar to transposing it). I'd suggest you to search the answer (or ask your question) on http://gis.stackexchange.com/. But you might skip the python part, since it is actually not that relevant.

Comment: @Falko But the coordinate system is the same. I just need to rearrange the elements in order to match with required coordinate POINTS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if it's really just a problem of reordering the elements, then you might be looking for something like this:

```py
from itertools import chain

Lat = [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]]

Lon = [[111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116],
       [121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126],
       [131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136]]

print zip(chain.from_iterable(Lat), chain.from_iterable(Lon))
```

But your question is really confusing. When asking on stackoverflow, try to break it down to some minimum example skipping all the stuff not relevant to the question.